# how to cp a big dataset to colab from google drive

Tags: google-colaboratory

I want to unzip a big dataset  to colab from google drive.But an error occurred during the unzip.And i try to download file from my drive.I got an error ：'download quota exceeded for this time,so you cant download it at this time'.I guess the download is restricted so an error occurred.So how to fit it?

Comment: I have the exact same error. My error was zipfile read error.
After I tried to download it, it gave me a restriction just like yours, and I believe this is why the zipfile will not unzip.

other zip programs also do not work (7zip etc.)

this is clearly a Google Drive error.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent `download quota exceeded for this time, so you cant download it at this time`.
You should add a star to this file. Then, back to your google drive. then download it.
I have to try it and able to download data.
https://tinhte.vn/thread/huong-dan-cach-tai-file-bi-gioi-han-so-lan-tai-tren-google-drive.2779276/

Comment: My file is used only by me.It is not a share file.And I had try it but did not help.Now I can't download any file in my google drive.And i want to cp file to colab.I got 'Input/output error'

Answer (score 0):

Transfer quotas reset over time, you should try again later.

To avoid consuming transfer quota, **copy the file from your Drive to the local disk before unzipping the file**.

```
!cp /content/drive/My\ Drive/tmp/somefile.zip /content
!unzip /content/somefile.zip
```